# Bash convert epoch to date, showing wrong time

Tags: bash, date, epoch

How come date is converting to wrong time?

```
result=$(ls /path/to/file/File.*)
#/path/to/file/File.1361234760790

currentIndexTime=${result##*.}
echo "$currentIndexTime"
#1361234760790

date -d@"$currentIndexTime"
#Tue 24 Oct 45105 10:53:10 PM GMT
```

Comment: 1361234760790 / (60*60*24*365) = 43164.47 years

Comment: not sure what that explains?

Comment: Roughly 43164 + 1970 ~= 45105 (43135.8 + 1970 to be more accurate) so the date is right

Comment: interesting, how can this date be printed correctly?

Comment: using http://www.epochconverter.com/, i get `GMT: Tue, 19 Feb 2013 00:46:00 GMT` which is desired result

Comment: on osx use `date -r 1504100044`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This particular timestamp is in milliseconds since the epoch, not the standard seconds since the epoch. Divide by 1000:

```
$ date -d @1361234760.790
Mon Feb 18 17:46:00 MST 2013
```

Comment: Yes, its due to timestamp in milliseconds.  I have also checked here http://epochconvert.com and get correct result  **Tuesday, 19 February 2013, 12:46:00 AM GMT**

Answer (score 27):

For Mac OS X, it's `date -r <timestamp_in_seconds_with_no_fractions>`

```
$ date -r 1553024528
Tue Mar 19 12:42:08 PDT 2019
```

or

```
$ date -r `expr 1553024527882 / 1000`
Tue Mar 19 12:42:07 PDT 2019
```

or

```
$ date -r $((1553024527882/1000))
Tue Mar 19 12:42:07 PDT 2019
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use bash arithmetic expansion to perform the division:

```
date -d @$((value/1000))
```

Note that "`value`" is a bash variable with the `$` being optional; i.e., `$value` or `value` can be used.